# How to handle route urls with variable numbers in them in Node.js with express?

Tags: regex, node.js, express, routes

In node.js with express, I want a url route like this

```
app.get('/class/^(\d+)$/feedback', function (req, res) {

});
```

so for example `/class/5/feedback` should be valid, but digits in the node.js regex doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: @omega Why don't you use params instead of regex?

Comment: Remove the "^" and "$" anchors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove anchors(`^` and `$`) from the regex and put it properly. You also need to escape `/` as `\/` and there is no need of `'` while using regex. Your final regex will look like

```
/^class\/(\d+)\/feedback$/
```

*Code*

```
app.get(/^class\/(\d+)\/feedback$/, function (req, res) {
     res.write(req.params[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us say the number is called 'id'. This is the better way:

```
app.get('/class/:id/feedback', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
});
```

:id is access through the 'params' keyword.